# Return Data and Type of mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, types, return-value

Consider the following 3 standard statements

```
$queryString = "SOME SQL SELECT QUERY";
$queryResult = mysql_query($queryString);
$queryArray = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult);
```

Question is :

If the result set of the query is empty, what will be the resultant datatype and value of `$queryArray` after all three statements are executed ?

Comment: can't you have done var_dump($queryArray); ?

Comment: @OrangeRind: `var_dump` would print `boolean(false)` if the boolean value *false* would have been passed.

Comment: oh, fine. thanks again!
You see, the php manual is too theoretical a thing for me to go through. directly asking specific questions seems to solve my problems and doubts much effectively. thanks to stackers like you all!
:D

Comment: Yeah, but still, function return types are part of the bread and butter of language documentation.  You really should consult your resources first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`mysql_fetch_array` manual page](http://docs.php.net/mysql_fetch_array):

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or **`FALSE`** if there are no more rows.

So the data type of the final return value would be [*boolean*](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Comment: OrangeRind - I would encourage you to officially "Accept" this answer if you find it to satisfactorily answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should Read The Fine Manual. All the `mysql_fetch_*` functions return false if the result set is empty. False is a boolean type, although types aren't super-important in PHP.

Maybe consider using PDO instead of `mysql_*`, because it (1) doesn't tie your PHP code to a particular database vendor (allowing you to test with sqlite databases, for instance), and (2) PDO is more performant than the `mysql_*` functions in general.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

> $num = mysql_num_rows($queryResult);

to find out how many rows are being returned.

Cheers